# How to get Primary MX IP from domain in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, host, mx-record

I am trying to write a bash script that will from a domain name find it MX records, from them figure out which is the primary (they are not always in order) and then find its IP.
(when there are more then one primary MX the first one found would be ok)

For example:

```
./findmxip.sh gmail.com
```

Would give me `173.194.71.26`. For me to do this I need to host gmail.com
then find the primary MX in the results and host it, getting its IP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get exactly 0 or 1 answers:

```
dig +short gmail.com mx | sort -n | nawk '{print $2; exit}' | dig +short -f -
```

You'll need a non-ancient `dig` that supports `+short`.

As noted there may be more than one "primary" MX as the preferences need not be unique. If you want all the IP addresses of all of the lowest preference records then:

```
dig +short oracle.com mx | sort -n | 
  nawk -v pref=65536 '($1<=pref) {pref=$1; print $2}' | 
  dig +short -f - | uniq
```

This does not handle the case where there is no MX record and the A record accepts email, an uncommon but perfectly valid configuration.

Sadly all the `dig` versions I've tested return 0 whether the domain exists or not (NXDOMAIN), and whether any MX records exist or not. You *can* catch a DNS time-out (rc=9) though. The related `host` command *does* return a non-zero rc with NXDOMAIN, but its behaviour is a little inconsistent, it's messy to script and the output harder to parse.

A poor man's error-checking version (inspired by *tripleee*'s comment) that might be slightly more robust depending on your `host` command is:

```
DOMAIN=gmail.com
if ! host -t any $DOMAIN >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  echo "no such domain"
elif ! host -t mx $DOMAIN >/dev/null 2>&1;  then
  echo "no MX records"
else
  dig +short $DOMAIN mx | sort -n | nawk '{print $2; exit}' | dig +short -f -
fi
```

(Perversely, you may require an *older* version of `host` (`bind-8.x`) for the `-t mx` test to work, newer versions just return 0 instead.)

This is just about the point people start <strike>backing away nervously</strike> asking why you're not using `perl`/`python`/`$MFTL`.

If you *really* need to write a robust version in bash, check out the [*djbdns*](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tools.html) CLI tools and [debugging tools](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/debugging.html) which are rather easier to parse (though sadly don't set user exit codes either).

Comment: +1 especially for `dig -f -`. This is obviously fragile; an error anywhere in the pipeline should be handled, and I suppose there are MX records with bare IP addresses, although it should be a CNAME.

Comment: @mr.spuratic If the CNAME of the MX being resolved to multiple IP's the output can contains multiple IP's. Eg. yandex.ru.
Optionally one could add '|head -n1' at the end.

Comment: Here is a version handling the case when there is no MX, or only one MX: `dig +short $DOMAIN mx| sort -n | awk '{mx=$2; if(!mx) { mx=$1 }; print tolower(mx);exit} END { if (!NR) print "no_mx";exit }'` (without the last part converting to IP address, and adding a lowercase conversion of the domain name)

Comment: Here is another version: `dig +noall +short $(dig +noall +short gmail.com mx | sort -h) | head -n1`

Comment: how to get this in a variable?